# How do i get foreign key table data using Entity Framework and Web Api in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My Code is :

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        ASITDbEntities db = new ASITDbEntities ( );
        // GET api/employee
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get ( )
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var result=db.Employees.ToList ()
            return result.ToList ( );
        }
}
```

I want to return employee district name from District table. It returns only district Id.

I tried `db.Employee.Include(e=>e.district).Tolist();`
But that did not work. Please help me.

Comment: "But did not work" What happened instead? Was there an error message? What are you expecting for the final result?

Comment: `db.Employees.Include(e=>e.district).Tolist();` shouuld do the trick unless there isn't actually a value set in the database for the `districtId`.

Comment: I Used It ,var result = db.Employees.Include ( e => e.district ).ToList ( ); it shows this error ,"A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'ASITDbModel.Employee' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'district'."

Comment: You should show the relevant parts of the class model. If `Employee` has something like `DistrictId` it's almost certain that you can add a navigation property `District` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly are you using DB first or Code-first. If code first, Does your entities looks like this?

```
Public class Employee{
  public int EmpId {get;set;}
  public int EmpName {get;set;}

  public int DistrictId {get;set;}
  public District District {get;set;}
}

public class District{
  public int DistrictId {get;set;}

  public List<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
}
```

It creates 1-1 relationship between Employee and District entities. 
So, now if you include `db.Employee.Include(e=>e.district).Tolist()`, should return you the complete District object.